# Deleting a cookie properly, but its still there?

Tags: php, cookies, remember-me

so this is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["usernameCookie"])){
    echo "welcome again, your username and password is " . $_COOKIE['usernameCookie'];
}else {

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = [
            'username' => $_POST['username'],
            'password' => $_POST['password']
        ];
        echo $_SESSION['user']['username'] . " = " . $_SESSION['user']['password'];

        if (!empty($_POST['remember'])) {
            setcookie("usernameCookie", $_SESSION['user']['username'] . " " . $_SESSION['user']['password'], time()+3600);
        };

        if (isset($_POST['log'])) {
            setcookie("usernameCookie","", time()-3600);
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        };
    };
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        ?>
        <form method="post">
        username:<input type="text" name="username" required>
        <br><br>
        Password:<input type="password" name="password" required>
        <br><br>
        Remember me?:<input type="checkbox" name="remember">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">

        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <a href="LoginPage.php" name="log">Log out</a>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

in pictures:

[image]

if the user inserted his username then password then it will take him to the same php page "as requested by my instructor" and print his name, password and a logout link like this:

[image: simple login/logout page]

as you can see, i wrote the code so that it will create the cookie "usernameCookie", so if the user checked the "remember me?" checkbox previously then it will print the same information as previously and store a cookie, if the user refreshed the page or let's say closed the page and opened it again within the cookie time, the it will show this page:

[image]

now, my problem is that if the user checked the box and pressed "log out" after that it will still show him as shown in the last picture "welcome again, your username and password is adam 12345" even though i clicked log out, here's the code that i wrote for logging out

```
 if (isset($_POST['log'])) {
            setcookie("usernameCookie","", time()-3600);
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        };
```

did i delete the cookie incorrectly? what's the solution?

and sorry if i rephrased the question badly, i'm new here :D

Comment: Storing passwords in sessions is a real bad idea.

Comment: The reason as to why your code isn't working is simple: `href` cannot pass a POST array. I should be making this in the answers area instead, heh. Edit: I closed the question instead. See my comment below.

Comment: Enable error reporting, you'll see that you'll get an undefined index notice.

Comment: also after session_destroy your want to redirect or refresh because the session vars will still be populated, which would be confusing